# Delegate not working while handling C# Serial Port response

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a simple .NET C# app that communicates with a USB device. If communication is successful, the DataReceivedHandler "should" take the device response (port.ReadExisting) and update the UI - a simple asp:label control.

I am aware that UI updates do occur on a different thread, and one must use a delegate to call the update function. I have tried a few different solutions, but haven't been able to get it work. I can confirm that communication between the computer and the device is successful.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPortCommunication
{
    public delegate void UpdateLogDelegate(string msg);

    public partial class button : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateLog(string msg)
        {
            lblLog.Text = msg;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 }

            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM8");

            port.BaudRate = 19200;
            port.Parity = Parity.Even;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.DataBits = 7;

            port.Open();

            port.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        }

        public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
            string incomingData = port.ReadExisting();

            UpdateLogDelegate log = new 
            UpdateLogDelegate(UpdateLog);
            log.Invoke(incomingData);

            port.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.  :)

Comment: You should create your `DataReceived` event before you write to the port, or you might miss your data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are understanding the delegates quite right.  The idea is you make a delegate and then make an instance of that delegate and assign it a function.  So in your DataReceived event it will always call the function it's set to.  You're creating a new instance but not assigning it a function correctly.  See my fixes below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPortCommunication
{
    public delegate void UpdateLogDelegate(string msg);
    public UpdateLogDelegate ULD;   //create instance of your delegate that you will assign a function to

    public partial class button : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateLog(string msg)
        {
            //the serial port datareceived event is on a different thread
            //you'll have to invoke to update your GUI
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblLog.Text = msg;
            });
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 }

            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM8");

            port.BaudRate = 19200;
            port.Parity = Parity.Even;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.DataBits = 7;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);   //move this before you write to the port

            //initialize your delegate to the UpdateLog function
            //but note, maybe if you had a Button2_click you could set ULD to a different
            //function and as data came in it would just call the correct function
            ULD = UpdateLog;    

            port.Open();

            port.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
        }

        public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //your port is already global so you dont need to re-declare it
            string incomingData = port.ReadExisting();

            ULD(incomingData);

            port.Close();   //I wouldn't close the port here, but for testing this is ok
        }
    }
}
```